# accessing a Map Object through the entries index

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, data-structures

Can a JS Map object be accessed through it's entry index without iteration?

Iterating I could get the the first entry with `myMap.entries().next().value` ,

 but ,
in order to get the last entry , I'd have to iterate all entries with a counter checking map size :

```js
var myMap = new Map();
myMap.set("a", "alpha");
myMap.set("b", "beta");
myMap.set("g", "gamma");


var firstMapIter = myMap[Symbol.iterator]().next().value;

console.log( last(myMap) )


function last(m){
  var i=0,
      iter = myMap[Symbol.iterator]();
  
  while(i++ < myMap.size)
  var res = iter.next().value;
  
  return res;
    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible to get the `Map` object that is iterated from a `MapIterator` instance (such as the one returned by `.entries()`).

Comment: but  the order from `MapIterator` is guaranteed ?

Comment: @maioman: Yes, it is. That said, you shouldn't use `Map`s if you need an ordered collection, `Map` iteration order is only *well-defined* to be consistent (also across implementations).